# Does DC longitudinal conductivity diverge/vanish for a noninteracting system?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, greens-functions

Consider a free electron system, say, a tight-binding lattice model. Does its DC longitudinal conductivity from the Kubo formula always diverge/vanish theoretically? Since there is not any scattering/relaxational process at all?

If so, how to see this from the Kubo formula?

Answer (score 0):

It can diverge and can not do it, depending, does given material have some Drude weight or does not. For 2-dimensional material for example there is popular topic of plasmons, which is based on the free charge carriers (and hence Drude weight) in the material. In this article https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.067402
for simplest models of graphenes it was shown that real part of the conductivity should go to the value of 2 at small frequencies. And for more complicated systems, like twisted bilayer graphene Drude weight was theoretically predicted and calculated https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/15/11/113050/meta. And in these measurements some Drude weight (corresponding plasmons) was observed https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07893.